# XSLT to display elements in nested node from the current node

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, nested, styles

```
given xml :
<transetx220a1>
          <trantypeenum>ST01834</trantypeenum>
          <trantypeval>834</trantypeval>
          <controlnumber>745029</controlnumber>
          <tranversionreleaseenum>v005010X220A1</tranversionreleaseenum>
          <tranversionreleaseval>005010X220A1</tranversionreleaseval>
          <segmentcount>32</segmentcount>
          <bgn>
            <purposecodeenum>BGN0100</purposecodeenum>
            <purposecodeval>00</purposecodeval>
            <referenceid>060743616745029</referenceid>
            <creationdate>20160506</creationdate>
            <creationtime>0744</creationtime>
            <timezoneenum>CT</timezoneenum>
            <timezoneval>CT</timezoneval>
            <actioncodeenum>RX</actioncodeenum>
            <actioncodeval>RX</actioncodeval>
          </bgn>
          <fileeffdate>
            <datetimeperiod>
              <dtptypeenum>DTP303</dtptypeenum>
              <dtptypeval>303</dtptypeval>
              <formatenum>D8</formatenum>
              <formatval>D8</formatval>
              <value>20160506</value>
            </datetimeperiod>
          </fileeffdate>
          <qtytrancontrols />
          <sponsorname>
            <partyidenum>P5</partyidenum>
            <partyidval>P5</partyidval>
            <entityname>Casey McCasland</entityname>
            <partyidqualenum>FI</partyidqualenum>
            <partyidqualval>FI</partyidqualval>
            <identifier>999999999</identifier>
          </sponsorname>
          <payername>
            <partyidenum>IN</partyidenum>
            <partyidval>IN</partyidval>
            <entityname>New Mexico Health Connections</entityname>
            <partyidqualenum>FI</partyidqualenum>
            <partyidqualval>FI</partyidqualval>
            <identifier>453416923</identifier>
          </payername>
          <tpa_brokername />
          <enrollment>
            <eligx220a1>
              <ins>
                <memberindenum>Y</memberindenum>
                <memberindval>Y</memberindval>
                <indrelenum>INS0218</indrelenum>
                <indrelval>18</indrelval>
                <maintenancetypeenum>INS03030</maintenancetypeenum>
                <maintenancetypeval>030</maintenancetypeval>
                <benefitstatusenum>A</benefitstatusenum>
                <benefitstatusval>A</benefitstatusval>
                <employmentstatusenum>AC</employmentstatusenum>
                <employmentstatusval>AC</employmentstatusval>
              </ins>
              <subscribernumber>
                <reftypeenum>REF010F</reftypeenum>
                <reftypeval>0F</reftypeval>
                <value>P700060195</value>
              </subscribernumber>
              <policynumber>
                <reftypeenum>REF011L</reftypeenum>
                <reftypeval>1L</reftypeval>
                <value>P900010001</value>
              </policynumber>
              <supplementalid>
                <referenceid>
                  <reftypeenum>REF0117</reftypeenum>
                  <reftypeval>17</reftypeval>
                  <value>001</value>
                </referenceid>
              </supplementalid>
              <memberleveldates>
                <datetimeperiod>
                  <dtptypeenum>DTP356</dtptypeenum>
                  <dtptypeval>356</dtptypeval>
                  <formatenum>D8</formatenum>
                  <formatval>D8</formatval>
                  <value>20160201</value>
                </datetimeperiod>
              </memberleveldates>
              <memb>
                <affiliatename>
                  <entityidenum>IL</entityidenum>
                  <entityidval>IL</entityidval>
                  <entitytypeenum>NM1021</entitytypeenum>
                  <entitytypeval>1</entitytypeval>
                  <lastname>Mcsasasas</lastname>
                  <firstname>Casss</firstname>
                  <idqualifierenum>NM10834</idqualifierenum>
                  <idqualifierval>34</idqualifierval>
                  <identifier>999999999</identifier>
                </affiliatename>
                <affiliateaddress>
                  <locationcodeenum>CY</locationcodeenum>
                  <locationcodeval>CY</locationcodeval>
                  <locationcodeidentifier>CURRY</locationcodeidentifier>
                  <addrline1>149 sssssss AVE</addrline1>
                  <city>CLOVIS</city>
                  <state>NM</state>
                  <zip>88101</zip>
                </affiliateaddress>
                <affiliatecontact>
                  <contact>
                    <comm>
                      <communication>
                        <commtypeenum>HP</commtypeenum>
                        <commtypeval>HP</commtypeval>
                        <value>5121212482</value>
                      </communication>
                      <communication>
                        <commtypeenum>EM</commtypeenum>
                        <commtypeval>EM</commtypeval>
                        <value>tfsasasl@farsasassant.com</value>
                      </communication>
                    </comm>
                    <functioncodeenum>IP</functioncodeenum>
                    <functioncodeval>IP</functioncodeval>
                  </contact>
                </affiliatecontact>
              </memb>
              <membdmg>
                <birthdateformatenum>D8</birthdateformatenum>
                <birthdateformatval>D8</birthdateformatval>
                <birthdate>19611111</birthdate>
                <genderenum>M</genderenum>
                <genderval>M</genderval>
                <maritalstatusenum>B</maritalstatusenum>
                <maritalstatusval>B</maritalstatusval>
              </membdmg>
              <empclass />
              <amtpolicy />
              <hlh>
                <healthcodeenum>N</healthcodeenum>
                <healthcodeval>N</healthcodeval>
              </hlh>
              <lui />
              <school />
              <responsibleperson />
              <dsb />
              <healthcov>
                <healthcoverage>
                  <hd>
                    <maintenancetypecodeenum>HD01030</maintenancetypecodeenum>
                    <maintenancetypecodeval>030</maintenancetypecodeval>
                    <insurancelineenum>HLT</insurancelineenum>
                    <insurancelineval>HLT</insurancelineval>
                    <coveragelevelenum>EMP</coveragelevelenum>
                    <coveragelevelval>EMP</coveragelevelval>
                  </hd>
                  <dtpcoverage>
                    <datetimeperiod>
                      <dtptypeenum>DTP348</dtptypeenum>
                      <dtptypeval>348</dtptypeval>
                      <formatenum>D8</formatenum>
                      <formatval>D8</formatval>
                      <value>20160201</value>
                    </datetimeperiod>
                  </dtpcoverage>
                  <policynumber>
                    <referenceid>
                      <reftypeenum>CE</reftypeenum>
                      <reftypeval>CE</reftypeval>
                      <value>93091NM001001000</value>
                    </referenceid>
                  </policynumber>
                  <provider>
                    <memberpcp>
                      <sequentialnumber>1</sequentialnumber>
                      <provider>
                        <affiliatename>
                          <entityidenum>P3</entityidenum>
                          <entityidval>P3</entityidval>
                          <entitytypeenum>NM1021</entitytypeenum>
                          <entitytypeval>1</entitytypeval>
                          <idqualifierenum>XX</idqualifierenum>
                          <idqualifierval>XX</idqualifierval>
                          <identifier>1437296522</identifier>
                        </affiliatename>
                        <affiliateaddress>
                          <addrline1>702 N 13th St</addrline1>
                          <city>Artesia</city>
                          <state>NM</state>
                          <zip>88210</zip>
                        </affiliateaddress>
                      </provider>
                    </memberpcp>
                  </provider>
                </healthcoverage>
              </healthcov>
              <lsloopheader>Item2700</lsloopheader>
              <report>
                <memberreport>
                  <sequentialnumber>1</sequentialnumber>
                  <reportcategory>
                    <partyidenum>N10175</partyidenum>
                    <partyidval>75</partyidval>
                    <entityname>PRE AMT TOT</entityname>
                  </reportcategory>
                  <refcategory>
                    <reftypeenum>REF019X</reftypeenum>
                    <reftypeval>9X</reftypeval>
                    <value>414.31</value>
                  </refcategory>
                  <reportcategorydate>
                    <dtptypeenum>DTP007</dtptypeenum>
                    <dtptypeval>007</dtptypeval>
                    <formatenum>D8</formatenum>
                    <formatval>D8</formatval>
                    <value>20150101</value>
                  </reportcategorydate>
                </memberreport>
              </report>
              <lelooptrailer>Item2700</lelooptrailer>
            </eligx220a1>
          </enrollment>
        </transetx220a1>
```

Tried XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

  <xsl:for-each select="/transetx220a1/sponsorname/entityname">
<div style="font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color: brown">
<xsl:value-of select="../entityname"/>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<span style="font-weight:bold">Date Format:</span>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/birthdateformatval, 'D8')">
Date Expressed in Format CCYYMMDD
  </xsl:if>
</div>

<div>
<span style="font-weight:bold">Date of Birth:</span>
<xsl:value-of select="../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/birthdate"/>
</div>


<div>
<span style="font-weight:bold">Gender:</span>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/genderval, 'M')">
Male
  </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
Female
     </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</div>

<div>
<span style="font-weight:bold">Relationship:</span>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'B')">
Registered Domestic Partner
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'D')">
Divorced
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'I')">
Single
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'M')">
Married
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'S')">
Seperated
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'U')">
Unmarried
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'W')">
Widowed
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(../../enrollment/eligx220a1/membdmg/maritalstatusval, 'X')">
Legally Seperated
  </xsl:if>
</div>

</div>
<div style="font-weight:bold;">
<xsl:value-of select="../../enrollment/eligx220a1/memb/affiliatecontact/contact/comm"/>

</div>
  </xsl:for-each>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output given :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div style="font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color: brown">Casey McCasland</div>
      <div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Date Format:</span>
            Date Expressed in Format CCYYMMDD

         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Date of Birth:</span>19611111
         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Gender:</span>
            Male

         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Relationship:</span>
            Registered Domestic Partner

         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="font-weight:bold;">

         HP
         HP
         5121212482


         EM
         EM
         tfsasasl@farsasassant.com


      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Desired Output :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div style="font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color: brown">Casey McCasland</div>
      <div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Date Format:</span>
            Date Expressed in Format CCYYMMDD

         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Date of Birth:</span>19611111
         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Gender:</span>
            Male

         </div>
         <div><span style="font-weight:bold">Relationship:</span>
            Registered Domestic Partner

         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="font-weight:bold;">
         <div>
         HP
         HP
         5121212482
         </div>
         <div>
         EM
         EM
         tfsasasl@farsasassant.com
         </div>

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I would like to display the comm values in different divs and show it in separate lines. Any help is appreciated.  I am trying to use a XML code and embed XSLT code and convert it to a html code and display it in a page. The basic idea behind this is using the sponsor name's Xpath "Casey Mccasland" display all the communication details in seperate lines.

Comment: That is not valid XML.  Where's the closing `</hi>`? Also, please show the desired output exactly as you want to see it.  Are you trying to generate HTML that can be styled with CSS, or something else?  What do you mean by _"control the style"_?

Comment: i just mentioned a sample xml there. the actual xml is too big.

Comment: Regardless, you are expected to provide valid sample data.  Also please answer the rest of my questions. Without those details your question is not answerable.

Comment: my idea is...given the member id of a data. (one value in xml tags). i have to retrieve all the values related to that member id . For example ,in the above example xml that i mentioned if "anupam" is my member id and 1,2 are my details . Using the xpath of anupam , i should be able to display 1 and 2 in different lines.

Comment: XML has nothing to do with "display".  Please clarify the context in which you are going to display the data.

Comment: `<abc>
 <name>
   <memberid>anupam </memberid>
 </name>
<hi>
  <hello> 1</hello>
  <hello> 2</hello>
</hi>
</abc>`

modified xml is given above and desired output should be :
anupam
1
2

Comment: I am planning to show a html file in which the values of xml are displayed. I have written a code in javascript  to embed the xsl to the xml and display a html code for that xml.

Comment: the output should be 
anupam (line break)
1 (line break)
2 (line break)

Comment: If you want an answer to your question you must show: (1) Correct, representative XML; (2) Expected HTML output from that XML; (3) the complete XSLT stylesheet; (4) The current actual output, including an explanation of what you think is wrong.  Please [edit] your post, do not add information in comments.

Comment: _"the output should be anupam (line break) 1 (line break) 2 (line break)"_ -- I believe what you really want is some HTML that renders that way, but it's not clear.

Comment: I have edited the post . can you have a look at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `comm` element looks like this:

```
<comm>
  <communication>
    <commtypeenum>HP</commtypeenum>
    <commtypeval>HP</commtypeval>
    <value>5121212482</value>
  </communication>
  <communication>
    <commtypeenum>EM</commtypeenum>
    <commtypeval>EM</commtypeval>
    <value>tfsasasl@farsasassant.com</value>
  </communication>
</comm>
```

But to display it, you are doing this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../enrollment/eligx220a1/memb/affiliatecontact/contact/comm"/>
```

This just outputs the concatenated text value of all descendant nodes, without formatting. You really need to select the `communication` elements separately to output a `div` for each, and then the children.

Try this instead of doing the `xsl:value-of`

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">
  <xsl:for-each select="../../enrollment/eligx220a1/memb/affiliatecontact/contact/comm/communication">
  <div>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are " * " and  " . " used for ? @Tim C

Comment: `*` will select an element regardless of the name, so in this case the expression will select the three child nodes of the `communication` element. `.` will select the current node.